# 'ignore nan' in numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy

The elementary functions in numpy, like mean() and std() returns np.nan when encounter np.nan. Can I make them ignore it?

Comment: Are you sure about mean() and std() ignoing nan? Why would nanmean() and nanstd() exist then?

Comment: That result evaluates to `np.nan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" functions like `np.mean` and `np.std` evalutates the NaN i.e the result you've provided evaluates to NaN.

If you want to avoid that, use `np.nanmean` and `np.nanstd`. Note that since you have only one non-nan element the std is 0, thus you are dividing by zero.

Comment: ooh.. then I misunderstood. Well, `np.mean` returns `NaN` if there is any so.. I don't think I understand the question then?